# How to make a braintree subscription with dropin UI and 3DS2?

Tags: braintree

I want to create a subscription page using drop-in UI.

**Client Side**:
I am done with the client-side. I have Drop-in UI implemented and I obtain a payment nonce.

**Server Side**:
On the server side I receive the nonce from the client but I can't create a subscription with that nonce(I received an unvaulted payment method). I need to create a payment method with this nonce. After this the nonce is consumed, so I need another nonce with 3DS secure (for the subscription creation).

From their documentation I understand that I need to create a second nonce (payment method nonce) and send again to the client for verification. I didn't found any sample of this verification...

**The question is how I obtain a second nonce that I need for subscription creation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drop-in UI generates a **nonce**, but this nonce is associated with a vaulted payment method, **only if you provide a customer_id when you generate the **client_token****. In this way you can obtain a bounce that you can use in **gateway.subscription.create**.

To summary the steps are:

1. (server) Create a customer without a payment method
2. (server) Generate a client_token with customer_id from step 1
3. (client) Generate drop-in UI using client token from step 2
4. (client) When the end-user adds his payment details drop-in generate a nonce associated with an already vaulted payment method
5. (server) Call subscription.create with the nonce from step 4

   gateway.subscription.create({
   "payment_method_nonce": clientNonce,
   "plan_id": planId,
   "merchant_account_id": merchantAccountId
   })

Answer (score 3):

Just checked the documentation for [3DS + subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/3d-secure/recurring-transactions#braintree-recurring-billing-subscriptions), I can see where there's confusion. You need to switch to Hosted Fields, not Drop-In.

This is because you need to do the following workflow, which Drop-In doesn't support:

1. Generate a payment method nonce out of a vaulted payment method token (server-side)
2. [Verify](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web/current/ThreeDSecure.html#verifyCard) that nonce using 3D Secure in your client. Successful results will have a new payment method nonce that is enriched with 3D Secure data. (on the client)
3. Use the generated 3D Secure enriched nonce in the [Subscription.create()](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/reference/request/subscription/create#create-with-3d-secure-enriched-payment-method-nonce) call.

3D Secure is a complex workflow, if you have additional questions on implementing this particular workflow, [contact Support](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/help)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so drop in is not compatible with subscription & 3DS same time

Comment: This is not true, you can check the https://stackoverflow.com/a/70003913/769677 answer